# mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/xvdl as 2: Invalid argument

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, raid0

I have existing `RAID0` setup with two disks. I have to add a new drive to it. But when I try to run the following command:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md/customer_upload /dev/xvdl
```

I get an error:

```
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/xvdl as 2: Invalid argument
```

How do I add a new disk to an existing RAID0?

I used the following steps to create RAID 0 initially:

```
 sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md/customer_upload --level=stripe --raid-devices=2 device_name1 device_name2
```

**EDIT**

Seems like you cannot add disk to RAID0.

I ran the following command and it made it `RAID4` How & Why I am still not clear

```
/dev/md/customer_upload --grow -l 0 --raid-devices=3 -a /dev/xvdl
```

I can see three disks in RAID4 but total space is still 2Tb

```
xvdf    202:80   0     1T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0     2T  0 raid4 /customer_upload
xvdg    202:96   0     1T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0     2T  0 raid4 /customer_upload
xvdl    202:176  0     1T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0     2T  0 raid4 /customer_upload
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [kernel.org RAID wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing):

> After the new disk was partitioned, the RAID level 1/4/5/6 array can
>   be grown

that is, RAID-0 is not eligible for growing.  You will need to backup all the data, recreate the array from scratch, and restore from backups.

Comment: I did `mdadm /dev/md/customer_upload --grow -l 0 --raid-devices=3 -a /dev/xvdl` and it made my setup `RAID4`, I can see all the three disks attached using `lsblk` but total space is still 2Tb. How to resolve this? It should be 3Tb since each disk is of 1Tb

Comment: Firstly, are you sure it changed the RAID level?  Can you cut-and-paste the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` into your question?  Secondly, have you grown the FS to fill the device?  You keep telling us you know things ("*total space is still 2Tb*") but you don't **show** us how you know them, which makes it difficult to comment.

Comment: added to question

Comment: A three-1TB-stripe RAID-4 should be 2TB usable (2 data 1 parity), which is what you say you see.  You need this to be a 3-stripe RAID-0, and I still think that means you'll need to backup, nuke, recreate, and restore.

Comment: How much space would I require for parity in RAID5?

Comment: The same; the only difference is that the parity blocks are striped across all three drives in 5, as opposed to all on one disc in 4.

Answer (score 10):

yes you can, to add one disk to **raid 0**

**mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=3 --add /dev/sdd**

or you can add several disks

**mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 --add /dev/sdd /dev/sde**

**raid-devices=4 total devices count with new disks**, raid 0 become raid 4 and after reshape will be raid 0 again

and these sysctl opts for reshape speed control **dev.raid.speed_limit_min** and **dev.raid.speed_limit_max**

Comment: thanks, this really works for me

Answer (score 0):

Ok I searched about 20 different unsolved articles and I finally figured it out by dumb luck.

I had the same issue.
I cloned the drive using `sfdisk -d | sfdisk` like the many manuals and blogs said. 
I later just opened `fdisk /dev/sdd` and then simply hit `w` to rewrite the partition table. This fixed my Invalid Argument error.

I hope this helps someone.